# How to pause background music if some activity have video to play in android?

Tags: android

There's some way to pause background music if on another activity have a video to play?

I've using this code to play music in all activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.ultahcover);
  mediaPlayer.start();

  memories.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        length=mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, kenangan_kita.class));
      }
      // here's an activity with video player
    });

@Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mediaPlayer.isPlaying(); //this is work to play on all activity but clashes with video music
  }
```

any idea to avoid clashes music player?

please help me

Comment: Have a look at this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/volume-and-earphones.html#acquiring-focus

Comment: @KenWolf thanks for the suggest link sir, but i'm low to using a logic with doc code, i'm much appriciate for a full code that's let me modify the code, :(

Answer (score 1):

Just request the audio focus, this will notify other apps that you need the focus now, and they should pause their playback:

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
// Request audio focus for playback
int result = am.requestAudioFocus(afChangeListener,
                         // Use the music stream.
                         AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                         // Request permanent focus.
                         AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);

if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
    // Start playback
}
```

Take a look on this official guide: [Handling Changes in Audio Output](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/volume-and-earphones.html)